# Redirecting OLE DB calls to ODBC to use tls 1.2 for communicating with database

Tags: sql-server, database, odbc, oledb

OLE DB defines the way that a client talks to a provider, the server who is supplying the data. The provider is a COM object which is created by calling CoCreateInstance(). After creating an instance of the provider, the consumer than talks to the provider using the OLE DB defined interfaces. These interfaces are acquired by calling QueryInterface().

ODBC is a C API for accessing databases.OLEDB is a similar interface that uses Microsoft's COM technology instead of the C API.

I have a library using OLE DB(SQLOLEDB) similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05ff346e-d3db-4f12-9ed9-1275a1ab74a7/help-me?forum=sqlexpress&forum=sqlexpress) for connecting and talking to a provider, the server who is supplying the data. Since SQLOLEDB does not support tls 1.2, now I have to upgrade to newer version of OLEDB(msoledbsql), but I see newer msoledbsql is not supported in Windows 7 platform(I want to use in windows 7, so this option is out).

So now the option left for me to work with tls 1.2 is to use odbc(verion 11). Since the API calls differ between OLEDB ad ODBC. I want to know is there way to use odbc through OLEDB calls by which I can communicate using tls 1.2 with the database. If this is possible I can make changes to my existing library by changing few calls or doing data conversions and achieve communication using tls 1.2, else I would end up writing a new library using odbc. Could someone help me by sharing knowledge on this.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810892.aspx) explains it can be achieved by creating an instance of the MSDASQL (ODBC) provider using CoCreateInstance method. But I do not understand it clearly, how this will work.